# how to cascade-delete an entry from a Postgres table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

In my Postgres database I have an `organisation` table. There is a one-to-many relationship between `organisation` and `employee`. The `employee` table itself has a `phone_number` child table, and so on.

I need to delete an organisation, so therefore employees of the deleted organisation also need to be deleted, and phone numbers of those employees also need to be deleted.

The obvious way to achieve this is with a series of SQL statements

```
-- delete the organisation with ID 4

delete from phone_number where employee_id in (
  select id from employee where organisation_id = 4
)

delete from employee where organisation_id = 4

delete from organisation where id = 4
```

This works fine when there are only 3 tables involved, but in reality there are many more than this, and it becomes difficult to manage as the schema changes.

Another option is to turn on delete cascading for all the foreign keys, e.g. in the employee table, define the organisation foreign key as

```
create table employee
(
    organisation_id varchar(255) not null
        constraint fk_organisation_employee
            references organisation
            on delete cascade

    -- remainder of table definition omitted
);
```

If we do this for all the relevant foreign keys, then deleting an organisation should cascade to the immediate child tables, then to the children of the immediate children, and so on.

However, it's slightly terrifying to have this delete cascading permanently enabled. Ideally I would like to enable it just when an organisation is deleted, but this does not appear to be possible.

The application in question is a Java application with uses Hibernate/JPA for persistence. JPA has [features that support automatic deletion of child entities](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval), so maybe it would be better to leverage these, rather than enabling cascade deletes at the database level?

Is one these approaches better than the others or is there another option that I haven't considered?

Comment: "However, it's slightly terrifying to have this delete cascading permanently enabled." Why? You want this behavior or you don't. And when you're not sure if you want it, then you know that you shouldn't use it.

Comment: "However, it's slightly terrifying to have this delete cascading permanently enabled." That is the purpose of GRANT/REVOKE. In this either do not grant delete or revoke it from all but a limited user base and leave the cascade delete in place. Now you have controlled deletes. Of course you could create a role that held the delete functionally and grant the role to the selected user base but not to all users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution that allows you to specify a delete graph separately, take a look at [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#updatable-entity-view-delete-cascading-orphan-removal) which allows you to do exactly that. On top of that, it will also be a bit faster, as it will execute all deletes in a single statement.